# How to turn four vectors of differing lengths into a long format dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, data-science

I am very new to R programming and have been provided the following data to implement a non-parametric test on. My issue lies in being able to turn this data (in R) into a long format data frame, so I may then conduct a histo/box plot. We aren't allowed to simply turn data into csv then read in, it has to be done in R.

A:1361,1466,1319,1426,1437,1541,1474,1386,1510,1373,1463,1305,1571,1224,1372
B:1581,1515,1606,1518,1395,1584,1671,1573,1454,1674,1459,1647
C:1482,1570,1575,1634,1542,1651,1189,1678,1391,1525
D:2084,1566,1990,1996,2052,1436,1808,1679,1981,2014,1759,1842,1603,1670,1845,2016,1621,2050,1690,1933

I've turned these into vectors but keep spitting error mssgs when I try to turn into data frame (vectors different lengths). Any pointers would be much help, I've been trying to troubleshoot for hours and my prof is no help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the source format: text file? csv? json? this text verbatim in the text file? If you have them in R already, please post them using `dput(.)`. Thanks!

Comment: What would you want your final data set to look like?

Comment: The source format was given in text file. Sorry, didn't know I was supposed to post using dput(.). I need the final data set to look like two columns, one with stacked A,B,C,D and the other with corresponding observations. I feel like it must be a very obvious answer that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack` to put into one long format.

I'll assume you are starting with a vector of strings,

```r
vec <- c("A:1361,1466,1319,1426,1437,1541,1474,1386,1510,1373,1463,1305,1571,1224,1372", "B:1581,1515,1606,1518,1395,1584,1671,1573,1454,1674,1459,1647", "C:1482,1570,1575,1634,1542,1651,1189,1678,1391,1525", "D:2084,1566,1990,1996,2052,1436,1808,1679,1981,2014,1759,1842,1603,1670,1845,2016,1621,2050,1690,1933")
```

We can split into a `list`,

```r
str(setNames(sapply(vecspl, `[`, -1), sapply(vecspl, `[[`, 1)))
# List of 4
#  $ A: chr [1:15] "1361" "1466" "1319" "1426" ...
#  $ B: chr [1:12] "1581" "1515" "1606" "1518" ...
#  $ C: chr [1:10] "1482" "1570" "1575" "1634" ...
#  $ D: chr [1:20] "2084" "1566" "1990" "1996" ...
```

From here, we can `stack(.)` it:

```r
stack(setNames(sapply(vecspl, `[`, -1), sapply(vecspl, `[[`, 1)))
#    values ind
# 1    1361   A
# 2    1466   A
# 3    1319   A
# 4    1426   A
# 5    1437   A
# 6    1541   A
# 7    1474   A
# 8    1386   A
# 9    1510   A
# 10   1373   A
# 11   1463   A
# 12   1305   A
# 13   1571   A
# 14   1224   A
# 15   1372   A
# 16   1581   B
# 17   1515   B
# 18   1606   B
# 19   1518   B
# 20   1395   B
# 21   1584   B
# 22   1671   B
# 23   1573   B
# 24   1454   B
# 25   1674   B
# 26   1459   B
# 27   1647   B
# 28   1482   C
# 29   1570   C
# 30   1575   C
# 31   1634   C
# 32   1542   C
# 33   1651   C
# 34   1189   C
# 35   1678   C
# 36   1391   C
# 37   1525   C
# 38   2084   D
# 39   1566   D
# 40   1990   D
# 41   1996   D
# 42   2052   D
# 43   1436   D
# 44   1808   D
# 45   1679   D
# 46   1981   D
# 47   2014   D
# 48   1759   D
# 49   1842   D
# 50   1603   D
# 51   1670   D
# 52   1845   D
# 53   2016   D
# 54   1621   D
# 55   2050   D
# 56   1690   D
# 57   1933   D
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `scan` the information. Then clean it from labels using `gsub`, `strsplit` at the commas, use `substr`ings as names, then `stack`. You could  continue automatically `type.convert`ing numerics, `aggregate` the `sum`s and `barplot` the result.

```
x <- scan(text='A:1361,1466,1319,1426,1437,1541,1474,1386,1510,1373,1463,1305,1571,1224,1372
B:1581,1515,1606,1518,1395,1584,1671,1573,1454,1674,1459,1647
C:1482,1570,1575,1634,1542,1651,1189,1678,1391,1525
D:2084,1566,1990,1996,2052,1436,1808,1679,1981,2014,1759,1842,1603,1670,1845,2016,1621,2050,1690,1933',
      what='character', quiet=TRUE)

x |> 
  gsub(pattern='\\w:', replacement='') |>
  strsplit(',') |>
  setNames(substr(x, 1, 1)) |>
  stack() |>
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) |>
  aggregate(values ~ ind, data=_, sum) |>
  barplot(values ~ ind, data=_, col=seq_len(length(x)) + 1)
```

[image]